# Issue in Python dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to compare two dictionary object with one to one correspondence. When there is update in `dict f` it should compare with `dict fa`. But in my code, when I updat `dict f`, it also updates `dict fa`. So the values are added up, which is meaningless for comparison. Can anybody help me with this?

```
def tym_save(node_add, data, f, fa, f2):
    if str(node_add) in f:
        # check for the older value
        f2 = tym_check(f[str(node_add)],fa[str(node_add)],f2)
    else:
        f[str(node_add)] = data
        fa = f
        print 'f-> ', f, 'fa-> ', fa
    return f, fa, f2
def tym_check(f_list,fa_list,f2_list):
    for i in range(len(f_list)):
        if f_list[i] > fa_list[i]:
            fa_list[i] = f_list[i]
        else:
            print f_list, fa_list, f2_list
            f2_list[i] = fa_list[i]
            f_list[i] = f_list[i] + f2_list[i]
    print f_list, fa_list,f2_list
    print 'yo'
    return f2_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = {}
    fa = {}
    f2 = [0,0,0,0]
    add = '0013a2'
    data = [1.0, 0.0, 0.342, 0.3]
    f, fa, f2 = tym_save(add, data, f, fa,f2)
    data = [2.0, 1.0, 0.342, 0.3]
    f[str(add)] = data    
    ## Here the fa is also updating.
    f, fa, f2 = tym_save(add, data, f, fa,f2)
    add = '0013a2'
    data = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    f, fa, f2 = tym_save(add, data, f, fa,f2)
```

Comment: what is the line `fa = f` suppose to accomplish? it is creating a second reference to the dict originally called `f`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Actually, `fa` is used for scanning `f` when it is arrived next with different values. And the assignment `fa = f` is at condition when there is no data in `f['0013a200']`.

Comment: yes, but you are assigning it as a pointer to the same object, hence appearing to update both.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Could you suggest me what can be done? Code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a conditional assignment `fa = f` in your `tym_save()` function. This is causing the undesired behavior you describe, as every time you update f you're also updating fa (they're pointing to the same spot). Instead, you want to copy f. You could do something like this:

```
import copy
fa = copy.deepcopy(f)
```

Comment: `tym_save()` function is required for saving the first time when the dictionary has been created from `f` to `fa`. Because, I want to use `fa` object for checking in values in next `f` and do some math to it.

Comment: I'm not saying you don't need it, i'm saying `fa = f` is creating your undesired behavior. Try substituting that line for what I have in my answer, and you will likely get the expected results.

Comment: Thank you. It Is working like a charm. But I would seek some help in my code. `tym_check()` would add the values on one-to-one corresponding on condition by checking `f` with `fa`. If it is lesser than it should add the values in `f` and if not pass on as it is.

Comment: I think you should open another question, then.